# AlarmManager double triggers

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I need the AlarmManager to be triggered after a certain time starting from a given time. I try this

```
if(mgr != null) mgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
    intent = new Intent(App.getContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(App.getContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3:00"));
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 36);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    long interval = 3 * 60 * 1000;

    mgr = (AlarmManager)App.getApplication().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

start time is correct, but interval is wrong. If i change calendar.getTimeInMillis() to System.currentTimeMillis() all work well. How to make it work width Calendar?

Comment: you have to set AlarmManager, not the set repeating it will occur multiple times.
Like below:
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()  
              + (i * 1000), pendingIntent);

Comment: I need the first time the AlarmManager is triggered at the specified time (in the example it is 11: 36) and then at the specified interval. It work, but interval is wrong

Comment: Repeating alarms are not accurate. If you need an accurate alarm you need to use other methods to do this. How far off is it?

Comment: For example, what methods can I use?

Comment: There is extensive documentation on the Android developer page about setting repeating alarms: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms In general, you should set a single alarm and when that triggers, you should do your work and set the next alarm. In this way, you are in control and there is only ever one single alarm set.